How to graph this function?
I want to come up with the right function to graph this shape that I drew. I tried adding up variants of e^sin(x), but the graph does not look very right to me. Do anyone know how I can approximate this shape using functions?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679582/creating-a-function-from-graph is somewhat similar, it may give you some ideas.

thanks! I did it! @GerryMyerson

I figured it out. Basically, I have to add three normal distributions together and scale them. 

Yes something like this

Thanks! That one is much more accurate @RaymondManzoni
